# Error with malloc while creating memory for list of struct pointers

Tags: c, pointers

For some reason, while trying to create an array of pointers of a struct called `Node`, I keep getting an error:

```
Node ret[2] = (struct Node*)malloc(2*sizeof(Node));
error: invalid initializer
```

Can someone please help me with that?

Comment: You are returning a struct Node pointer. Use Node *ret = ..., it will point to the first element of the array

Answer (score 3):

```
Node ret[2] = (struct Node*)malloc(2*sizeof(Node));
```

should probably be:

```
Node *ret = malloc(2 * sizeof(*ret));
```

That's because you need a pointer to the memory, not an array. With an array, it's initialisation, which would require a braced init list. Note that this only provides memory for the *pointers,* not the things they point at - they need to be allocated separately if you wish to use them.

You'll probably notice two other changes as well:

- I've removed the cast on the `malloc` return value. This serves no purpose in C since the `void*` returned can be implicitly cast to other pointer types. In fact, there are situations where explicit casts can lead to subtle problems.
- I've used `*ret` as the variable to get the size rather than the type. This is just habit of mine so that, if I change the type to (for example) `tNode`, I only have to change it in one place on that line - yes, I'm basically lazy :-) Note that this is just a preference, doing it the original way has no adverse effect on the program itself, just developer maintenance.

Comment: UV for `*ret` and lazy.

Answer (score 1):

I think your struct is typedef ed

```
Node ret[2]  = ( struct Node* ) malloc( 2 * sizeof(Node) );
```

it should be

```
Node *rec[2] = { malloc(sizeof(Node)) , malloc(sizeof(Node)) };
```

or

```
Node *rec    =  malloc(2*sizeof(Node));
```